# Plug-in on QGIS that could help to draw buildings

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I need to draw a lot of buildings from a city in Latin America, a friend of mine told me that he saw someone using a plug-in to draw buildings automatically with some errors but he doesn't know which plug-in is, so do you know if that plug-in exists or what can I do to make this task easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called `Mapflow`. Using QGIS 3.28.8 you can install it under *Plugins* -> *Manage and Install Plugins*. You can easily import a basemap, zoom-in to your area of interest and then click the icon and follow the image attached:
[image: flowchart]

The results:
Initial basemap:
[image: before]

Results of the plugin:
[image: after]

The results aren't 100% accurate. You still need manual inspection, but the plugin does a pretty good job. Keep in mind that the bigger the area of interest the longer it will take to finish the processing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give it a try

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please accept it by selecting the tick icon so others with similar issues can found the solution.